# Is it possible to change the definition of structs at runtime?

Tags: c, struct, runtime

I don't know why you would ever *want* to do this, but I was curious if anyone knew the answer. Is it possible at run time to use one struct definition for a while, and then later change that definition?

i.e.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}my_struct;
```

and later on...

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}my_struct;
```

Comment: Literally, no. Conceptually? You can do almost anything if you set your mind to it.

Comment: Impossible! Use different structs or use an array instead.

Comment: Structure definition no, but you can use pointers and typecast as appropriately. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Structure definitions have no bearing on runtime, anyway, besides their utility increating assembly instructions and constants with regard to the structure's size, where it's fields are, and memory alignment, where needed. Type info is compiled away... There are reasons C header files exist, and I'm pretty sure that is one of them.

Comment: Versioning of APIs is possible usage of similar behavior - there are multiple _EX structures in WinAPI that extend older versions - [FORMAT_EX_PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364551(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FORMAT_PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364552(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What does this even mean? Surely you don't think that your source file is executing at run time?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the definition of a given type, but there's nothing wrong with casting it to a totally *different* type, assuming the underlying data is similarly laid out and otherwise compatible.

For example, consider:

```
struct s_xyzzy {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct s_plugh {
    int a;
    char b0;
    char b1;
    char b2;
    char b3;
};

struct s_xyzzy *xyzzy = malloc (sizeof (*xyzzy));
((struct s_plugh *)xyzzy)->b0 = 'x';
```

By casting `xyzzy` to a different but compatible type, you can access the fields in a different way.

Keep in mind that compatibility is important and you have to know that the underlying memory will be correctly aligned between the two structures.

You can also do it by placing both structures into a union, using overlapped memory.

Comment: And that's how Objective-C was born...

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about *runtime polymorphism*, then it can be made to work, but you have to know what you're doing. Read [ooc.pdf](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) by Axel Schreiner.