# Modify Struct Fields during runtime

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I need to modify the fields of some structures during runtime. So depending on a parameter passed when you run the executable it should generate a different type of struct.

```
#if (PARAM_SET)
    typedef struct{
        char fetch[FILE];
        uint32_t bin;
        uint32_t bin_1;
        uint32_t bin_2;
    }
    HELPER;

    typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)){
         char job[4];
         uint32_t last;
         uint32_t liv_1;
         uint32_t liv_2;
         uint32_t dipr;
         uint32_t notch;
         uint32_t cnt;
         uint32_t max;
         char path[MAX_HEAD_PATH];
         HELPER for[MAX_NUM];
    }
    BOARD;

#else
    typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)){
        char job[4]
        uint32_t nxt;
        uint32_t prv;
        uin32 boards;
        char path[MAX_NUM];
    }
    BOARD;
#endif
```

Comment: That's not possible in C. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with that approach?

Comment: basically you need 2 structs and decide at run time which one to use. or use a union

Comment: @Quentin I need to be compatible with old code. So the old version uses one type of struct and the new one is using the other.. But the struct is passed as a parameter to other functions and I cant modify those functions thats why I cant create two structs with different names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the definition of structs at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117154/is-it-possible-to-change-the-definition-of-structs-at-runtime)

Comment: OK.. these structs, are they passed round by address, or copied?  By address, good, copied, bad:(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit by address

Comment: @pm100 How would  use a union for this?

Comment: @homeGrown OK, so you can do it, maybe.  Use a combined struct that has both variants, but add a pointer field at the end of the second struct that points back at the start of the first struct.  Then given the address of either, you can get back to the address of the whole.  Maybe that would do?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Could you post some code illustrating that if possible?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. With one you would have an answer by now, instead of many comments questioning the context....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter structs at runtime (i.e. after the program has been compiled).

But you can provide both types of structs (with distinct names) and adapt your code such that it uses the correct type based on parameters/conditions evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
     typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)){
        char job[4];
        uint32_t last;
        uint32_t liv_1;
        uint32_t liv_2;
        uint32_t dipr;
        uint32_t notch;
        uint32_t cnt;
        uint32_t max;
        char path[MAX_HEAD_PATH];
        HELPER for[MAX_NUM];
     }
     BOARDA;

    typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)){
        char job[4]
        uint32_t nxt;
        uint32_t prv;
        uin32 boards;
        char path[MAX_NUM];
        BOARDA *basePtr;
    }
    BOARDB;

    typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)){
       BOARDA borda;
       BOARDB bordb;
    }
    BOARD;
```

Initialize basePtr to point at BOARD, then you can always get the base address of the whole struct back from a BOARDA or BOARDB address.